# direct sum of noetherian modules is noetherian

Tags: modules, noetherian, direct-sum

We say that an $A$-module $M$ is Noetherian if all of its submodules are finitely generated. Having that definition in mind can anyone give me some hints to prove that if $M$ and $N$ are Noetherian modules then $M \oplus_A N$ must be Noetherian?

The problem I'm having is that an arbitrary submodule $Q$ of $M \oplus_A N$ is not necessarly of the form $Q = \bar{M} \oplus \bar{N}$ where $\bar{M}$ and $\bar{N}$ are submodules of $M$ and $N$ respectively. So I am out of ideas, and will be very happy to recieve some help.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: first show that if $P \subseteq Q$ are $A$-modules, then $P, Q/P$ Noetherian implies $Q$ Noetherian.

Comment: This would be a direct consequence of the fact that if: $ 0 \rightarrow N' \rightarrow N \rightarrow N'' \rightarrow 0$ is a s.e.s then $N$ is Noetherian iff $N'$ and $N''$ are. Now, is there a simple way of proving that using the definition I gave?

Comment: That is in fact easy to prove, I think. Take a submodule $Q$ of $N$ and consider the submodules $\pi(Q)$ and $i^{-1}(Q)$, they are finitely generated and with a little bit of work you can show that the generators of both submodules can be sent to a set in $N$ that can generate $Q$. That would prove the implication that would be useful for us, that is $N'$ and $N''$ Noetherian $\implies$ $N$ Noetherian

Comment: $i:N' \rightarrow N$ and $\pi: N \rightarrow N''$ would be the exact sequence homomorphisms

Comment: So then applying this to $M \oplus_A N$ we have that $(M \oplus_A N)/(M \oplus \{0\}) \simeq N$ is Noetherian and $M \oplus \{0\} \simeq M$ is Noetherian so $M \oplus_A N$ is Noetherian. Or one could alternatively use the exact sequence $0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow M \oplus_A N \rightarrow N \rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L_1\subseteq L_2\subseteq\cdots$ be an ascending chain of sub-modules of $M\oplus N$. Then $L_1\cap N\subseteq L_2\cap N\subseteq\cdots$ is stationary, so for some $k$ we have $L_k\cap N=L_{k+1}\cap N=\cdots$.

Similarly, $(L_1+N)/N\subseteq(L_2+N)/N\subseteq \cdots$ will be stationary, so for some $\ell$ we have $L_\ell+N=L_{\ell+1}+N=\cdots$.

Now for any $n\ge\max\{k,\ell\}$ let $x\in L_{n+1}\setminus L_{n}$. Since $L_n+N=L_{n+1}+N$, we have $x\in N$. However, then $x\in (L_{n+1}\cap N)\setminus (L_n\cap N)$, which is impossible.

Comment: doesn't in your 2nd paragraph you should have written $(L_l + N)/N = (L_{l+1} +N)/N=...$?

Comment: also in 3rd para I think you meant $n\geq max${k,l}. Am I right?

Comment: @James sorry, yes, good catch, I fixed the typo. As for your first comment, yes, that is what the direct implication is, but $L_\ell+N=L_{\ell+1}+N=\cdots$ is an easy consequence.